# Android - How to add to ViewFlipper 2 different layouts s.t each has one YouTubePlayerView?

Tags: android, youtube-api, embedded, viewflipper

Is it possible to add to ViewFlipper 2 different layouts one YouTubePlayerView ?
I tried to do something like the code I added, but the player collapses.Is there any way to initialize the player again after the ViewFlipper shows the next view?

```
 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

        <TextView
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

        <TextView
        </TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>`
```

Comment: *but the player collapses* - what do you mean by collapses?

Comment: @Luksprog If I play video and then change the current YouTubePlayerView to the second one there is black screen and it is not playing anything. It turns out that the problem I have is : YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. So when the flipper view changes the view and puts one on top of other and then It is not playing, Is there any solution for that? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't worked with the youtube API but it seems it only allows playing content while the player is visible to the user(the Youtube app works this way, I think they have something in the TOS about this). The solution is to keep a single instance of the Youtube player and only flip the other widgets of the layout.